# In Jdbc when i view record from table I get varible some value one and varible some value wo not the value itself

Tags: java, jdbc

I have make java data base connectivity and here is my code.My problem is that when i view the record from database ie `select * from recordtbl;` then I dont get the values that must be in these variable `Varible Filename =somevalue1;`

```
variable checksumno =somevalue two;
```

The code is -

```
package md5IntegrityCheck;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;


public class MD5IntegrityCheck
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
    throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
  {


      Connection con=null;
      PreparedStatement pst=null;

       try
        {
           Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");   
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:recordtbl","scott","tiger");
          System.out.println("Step 1");
          System.out.println(con.isClosed());




          // get the file name here and store it in filename variable;


          String filename="somevalueone ";
          String chksumno="somevaluetwo";



          System.out.println("Step 2");
          pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into recordtbl values(?,?)");
          //System.out.println(pst.isClosed());
          System.out.println("Step3");
          pst.setString(1,filename);
          System.out.println("Step 4");
          pst.setString(2,chksumno);
          System.out.println("Step 5");
          pst.execute();
          System.out.println("Statement was EXECUTED!");
      } 
      catch(Exception e)
        {
         System.out.println("ERROR : "+e);
        }


    if (args.length <= 0)
    {
      Md5Gui gui = new Md5Gui();
      gui.runGui();
    }
    else
    {
      DoWork runningProgram = new DoWork();
      runningProgram.run(args);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if you say you 'dont get the values that must come in these variable' do you mean they have some other values or is there no entry in your table? if it is the first: maybe you could post the result of a select statement (issued on a console/client for your db)?

Comment: yea i havent posted the result to select statement ...chk my code please nd correct if u can

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing a `commit()` and also not closing the connection.  Even though the default setting in JDBC is `autocommit=true`, [the spec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close%28%29) is pretty clear:

> It is strongly recommended that an
>   application explicitly commits or
>   rolls back an active transaction prior
>   to calling the close method. If the
>   close method is called and there is an
>   active transaction, the results are
>   implementation-defined.

Also, without commit, if later code opens a different DB connection, that connection may not see the updates from earlier in the code.  Add a `commit()` after the insert.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.  Get rid of all those print statements and use a debugger to step through the code if you must.

Are you connecting to Oracle?  If yes, why are you using an ODBC driver instead of an [Oracle Type IV JDBC driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html)?

```
package md5IntegrityCheck;

import java.sql.*;


public class MD5IntegrityCheck
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
       Connection con=null;
       PreparedStatement pst=null;

       try
       {
           // Are you trying to connect to Oracle?  Why aren't you using an Oracle JDBC driver?
           Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");   
           con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:recordtbl","scott","tiger");
           String filename="somevalueone ";
           String chksumno="somevaluetwo";
           pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into recordtbl values(?,?)");
           pst.setString(1,filename);
           pst.setString(2,chksumno);
           int numRowsInserted = pst.execute();
           System.out.println("# rows inserted: " + numRowsInserted);
       } 
       catch (Exception e)
       {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
       finally
       {
           try { if (pst != null) pst.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
           try { if (con != null) con.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: thq very much for ur cooperatin    but compiler is asking to chage this to boolean .  int numRowsInserted = pst.execute();              If I  do this  it generate error  .please guide me

Comment: # rows inserted: false     this is the error if i chage data type to Boolen

Comment: change  `pst.execute()` to `pst.executeUpdate()` this will give you the number of changed/added rows

Comment: Thanks .yes I want to connect to Oracle ..Wast'nt ther ORacle Drivers?